# I created a Azure Kubernetes Cluster with Kubenet networking where all my production is running. I would like to change it to CNI. Is that possible?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I can't find any link or way to change it. Please let me know if this is possible, if yes please share the detailed steps.

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing, AKS allows setting the network plugin only at the time of cluster creation. So if you have an AKS cluster provisioned with `kubenet` network plugin and you want to switch to `Azure CNI`, then currently the only way to achieve that is by recreating the AKS cluster with network plugin set to Azure CNI.

Please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aks-migration) for migration considerations and guidelines.