# How should I change my AKS cluster networking from Kubenet to Azure CNI?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, networking, azure-aks

I have created a Azure Kubernetes Cluster with Kubenet networking and it's running for my production environment. Now I would like to change it from Kubenet to CNI. I don't see any option.

How should I configure this without impacting my Production environment?

Please update

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can not switch network plugins in public cloud clusters, you have to recreate them. Even in self hosted clusters it can't be done without downtime.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will create new cluster and move all my existing applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Create a new cluster

This question has been asked before, checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/69296030

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I will try to create a cluster with Azure CNI network and move all my workloads.

Comment: Do you have any spec doc for to migrate all workloads from the existing cluster to the new cluster in azure. Thanks

Comment: Velero may fit your requirement. Ref: https://velero.io/docs/v1.11/migration-case/

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will have a look.